# WPF Prism MEF View lazy loading

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am discovering my views via MEF and Prism. However the constructor imports things which I do not want to load until after the full bootstrap has completed.

Rather than MEF go and instantiate all these objects for me at bootstrap time, I just want to register a View with MEF and a particular region, however only to construct and load it when I navigate to it for the first time.

Is this possible?

```
[Export("LegacyEntry")]
    [ViewExport]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
    public partial class LegacyEntry
    {
        public IEntryViewModel ViewModel
        {
            set => DataContext = value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add `Lazy<T>` when importing the module.
Something like this:

```
[Import]
Lazy<LegacyEntry> LegacyEntry { get; set; }
```

or multiple

```
[ImportMany]
IEnumerable<Lazy<LegacyEntry>> LegacyEnties { get; set; }
```